Sources about Glasser's master theorem
I'm trying to find sources that talk about Glasser's master theorem. 
The theorem states that:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F(x)dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F(u)dx
$$
Where $u = x - \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \frac{a_j}{x-C_j}$, $(a_j)$ is a sequence of positive constants and $C_j$ are real constants.

I would like to find more information regarding this theorem.
At the moment, the sources that I was able to find that mention this theorem explicitly are Glasser's original paper, " A Remarkable Property of Definite Integrals," the Wikipedia page and Wolfram MathWorld's web source.
I've found sources which claim to talk about a "master theorem", but they seem to talk about an irrelevant type of transform.
I was trying to find other sources which talk about the transformation which Glasser originally wrote about, but I couldn't find a lot.
I did find that Pólya and Szegö wrote about this transform in "Problem And Theorems In Analysis $\tt I$" in pt. $\tt II$, problem ${\bf 118.1}, \mbox{p.}\ 79$.
Moreover, I found some conflicting definitions regarding the Cauchy–Schlömilch transformation.
The Wikipedia page describes the substitution as $u = x - 1/x$, whereas the article "The Cauchy–Schlömilch transformation" by
Amdeberhan et al., wrote that the transformation is
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} f((ax – bx^{-1})^2)dx = \frac{1}{a} \int_{0}^{\infty} f(y^2)dy
$$
Are both definitions equivalent ?.

Thank you for all those who can help me with this.

I was able to find another paper which cites Glasser's theorem, "Nonlinear recursions on the reals and a problem of Graham" by Steinerberger, https://arxiv.org/abs/2401.04058

Notice that I've specified the variable $u$ below. I've edited the formula so it'll make better sense.

In the paper 'Which functions preserve Cauchy laws" Proceedings of the AMS 1977 Vol 37 pages 277- 286, yours truly proved the following : if $\mu$ is a singular bounded measure on $R$ then
$$f(x)=x-\int_R \frac{\gamma x+1}{x-\gamma}\mu(d\gamma)$$ preserves the Lebesgue measure. The Glasser theorem is the particular case
$$\mu(d\gamma)= \sum_i a_i \delta_{C_i}(d\gamma).$$
